# Gamma Probability Density Funtion Denominator $\Gamma(r)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Does $\Gamma(r)$ in the probability density of Gamma Distribution

$ f_X(x,\lambda,r) = \frac{(\lambda \cdot x)^{r-1} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(r)}$

always equal to $(r-1)!$  ?

If so, why not just replace $\Gamma(r)$ with $(r-1)!$ in the function?

Comment: If $r$ is an integer then you have an [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) and can write the density with a factorial

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 1):

No that is true for $r>0$ which are integers. Generally
$$
\Gamma(r)=\int_{0}^\infty x^{r-1}e^{-x}\, dx \quad (r>0)
$$
In particular $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: How does restricting $r$ to positive integers turn $\Gamma(r)=\int_{0}^\infty x^{r-1}e^{-x}$ into $(r-1)!$  ?